# Implementing a relation on a data structure

Tags: prolog

I have the following simple Prolog program that, through the use of data structure, represents a family composed of husband, wife and children list:

```
family(
    person(bob, smith, date(7,may,1968), 30000),
    person(ann, smith, date(18,july,1970), 32000),

    [person(dave, smith, date(1,june,1984), 0),
     person(edna, smith, date(25,may,1990), 0)]
).

family(
    person(mario, rossi, date(7,may,1968), 30000),
    person(lucia, verdi, date(18,july,1970), 32000),

    [person(luca, rossi, date(1,june,1984), 5000),
     person(maria, rossi, date(25,may,1990), 0),
     person(paolo, rossi, data(16, april, 1980), 10000)]
).

family(
    person(carlo, bianchi, date(7,may,1968), 30000),
    person(flavia, blabla, date(18,july,1970), 32000),

    [person(figlio1, bianchi, date(1,june,1984), 0),
     person(figlio2, bianchi, date(25,may,2001), 0),
     person(figlio3, bianchi, data(16, april, 1980), 10000),
     person(figlio4, bianchi, data(10, april, 1978), 20000)]
).

family(
    person(no, no, date(7,may,1968), 30000),
    person(no, no, date(18,july,1970), 32000),
    []
).


/* Regola che mostra i mariti: */
husband(X) :- family(X,_,_).

/* Regola che mostra l mogli: */
wife(X) :- family(_,X,_).

/* Regola che mostra i figli:
   X è figlio se in una famiglia c'è una lista di figli e se X appartiene
   alla lista dei figli: */
child(X) :- family(_,_,Children),
        member(X,Children).
```

This is very simple. By some facts I represent some family and I have some rule to perform some query (to obtain the husbands, the wifes, if X is a child in a family, if a person exist in a family, the salary of a person and the date of birth of a person)

OK, until now I have no problem.

Then I have the following exercise related to the previous program: **Write a rule that calculates the total salary of all the children in each family**

So I have to calculate a value that I have call ChildrenIncoming that represents the sum of the salary (the last value in the person data structure representing a child in a family data structure) of all the children belonging to a specific family

I am finding many problems to implement this functionality.

I am started from easier task (for example retrieve the salary of an husband) like this:

```
husbandIncoming(HSurname, HIncoming) :-  husband(HSurname),  % Seleziona un cognome
                         salary(HSurname, HIncoming).
```

I have try to calculate the ChildrenIncoming value trying to do something like it (that it is incomplete and don't work):

```
childrenList(Husband,ChildrenList) :- family(Husband,_,ChildrenList).

/* If ChildrenList is empty: ChildrenIncomung value 0 */
childrenIncoming(Husband,[],0).

childrenIncoming(Husband,ChildrenList,ChildrenIncoming) :-
    childrenList(Husband,ChildrenList),
    ChildrenList = [Head|Tail],
                               childrenIncoming(Husband,Tail,TailIncoming),
                               salary(Head, ChildrenIncoming).
```

first thing is that I identify a family by the husband so I can retrieve the **ChildrenList** using the **childrenList** rule (this rule works well).

Then I would calculate the sum of all the salary of all person that are inside this ChildreList and to do that I introduced the relation **childrenIncoming** that have to calculate it.

This relation start by the **fact** that simply say:

```
childrenIncoming(Husband,[],0).
```

If a family (having Husband as paterfamilias) have empty children list, then the total incoming of the children is 0.

Then I have introduce a rule (wrong) that should calculate this value in the case of non-empty children list.

The reasoning behind this rule is that:

1) A not empty children list contains person.

2) a non-empty list can be divided into an Head of the list (that is a person) and a Tail sublist (a list of person)

3) the head is a person and have a salary

4) the tail contains persons and each one have a salary

But I don't know how mix these ideas in the right way to obtain the desired result (the value of the total incoming of all person in the children list)

I don't know if this kind or reasoning is good or if I am wrong from the beginning.

Comment: Recursion, my dear Watson.

Comment: yes...I know...I have try but all my efforts are failed...can you help me :-/

Comment: @AndreaNobili: Please put more effort into your questions. You copy half of the text from one question to the next without ever proofreading it. Also, use a spell checker.

Comment: Spellchecker, and please try to make your questions shorter and more to the point, with _minimal_ examples showing your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add these predicates to family/3 facts

```
husband(family(H, W, C), P) :- family(H, W, C), H = person(P,_,_,_).
children(family(_, _, C), C).
income(P, I) :- P = person(_,_,_,I).

childrenIncoming(Family, ChildrenIncoming) :-
  children(Family, Children),
  sum_income(Children, 0, ChildrenIncoming).

sum_income([], Sum, Sum).
sum_income([C|Children], SoFar, Sum) :-
  income(C, I),
  Updated is I + SoFar,
  sum_income(Children, Updated, Sum).
```

with this query you get

```
?- husband(F, mario), childrenIncoming(F,I).
F = family(person(mario, rossi, date(7, may, 1968), 30000), person(lucia, verdi, date(18, july, 1970), 32000), [person(luca, rossi, date(1, june, 1984), 5000), person(maria, rossi, date(25, may, 1990), 0), person(paolo, rossi, data(16, april, 1980), 10000)]),
I = 15000 .
```

Comment: Nice predicate name "childrenIncoming" !  Life is like that.

Comment: Tnx. Now I will study it. Meanwhile I have found a personal solution (looking some example of a collegue) that, at first, seems like your. that calculate the total incoming of an entire family...Prolog is hard !!!

Answer (score -1):

I also create this one that calculate the total incoming of all components of a specific family:

```
/* FATTO (CASO BASE): Se la lista dei figli è una lista vuota, non ci
                      sono figli quindi la somma dei redditi dei figli è 0
*/
somma([],0).

/* REGOLA (CASO GENERALE): La lista dei figli non è vuota quindi può essere
   decomposta in un'HEAD (person(_,_,_,E) ed in una sottolista L.

   SE è VERO che: il valore della somma di tutti gli elementi nella
   sottolista L è S1 ed è VERO che il valore di S è S1+E allora è VERO
   che la somma dei redditi nella lista [H|L] è S

*/
somma([person(_,_,_,E)|L],S):- somma(L,S1),
                   S is S1+E.

/* Una famiglia è identificata dal COGNOME DEL MARITO.
   Il REDDITO TOTALE di una famiglia è la somma del reddito del marito +
   reddito moglie + la somma dei redditi di tutti i figli nella lista
   dei figli.
*/
reddito(C,R):- family(person(_,C,_,RP), person(_,_,_,RM), FIGLI),
           somma(FIGLI,RF),
           R is RF+RP+RM.
```

The comments are in italian but I think that looking the code is pretty simple understand what it means :-)